# Change iconv() replacement character

Tags: php, iconv

I am using `iconv()` to replace characters for an api request like this:

```
$text = iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT", $text);
```

This works great, however when an unknown character is encountered it gets replaced by a `?`.  Is there any straightforward way to change the substitution character to something else?  Say a space?  I know about the setting for mb functions `mb_substitute_character()` - but this doesn't apply to `iconv()`.

Example:

```
$text = '? € é î ü π ∑ ñ';
echo iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT", $text), PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
? EUR e i u ? ? n
```

Desired Output:

```
? EUR e i u     n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there's no translit function that lets you specify your own replacement character, but you can work around it by implementing your own simple escaping.

```php
function my_translit($text, $replace='!', $in_charset='UTF-8', $out_charset='ASCII//TRANSLIT') {
    // escape existing ?
    $res = str_replace(['\\', '?'], ['\\\\', '\\?'], $text);
    // translit
    $res = iconv($in_charset, $out_charset, $res);
    // replace unescaped ?
    $res = preg_replace('/(?<!\\\\)\\?/', $replace, $res);
    // unescape
    return str_replace(['\\\\', '\\?'], ['\\', '?'], $res);
}

$text = '? € é î ü π ∑ ñ \\? \\\\? \\\\\\?';
var_dump(
    $text,
    my_translit($text)
);
```

Result:

```
string(36) "? € é î ü π ∑ ñ \? \\? \\\?"
string(29) "? EUR ! ! ! p ! ! \? \\? \\\?"
```

I'm not certain why the transliteration output is different on my system, but the character replacement works.

Comment: Thanks - I was thinking of doing something like that myself but it felt a bit hacky.  Appreciate your input!